# Merged two collections with foreach data not displaying in meteor template

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I am new to meteor and have two Mongo collections, `user` and `patient`. I have concatenated them, in console this is displaying data but not in the html template. I am able to show data in objects in the console but not on my html template as seen in the image below:

[image: Patient Screen with console logged data]

What I have tried so far:

```
Template.showpatient.helpers({
    'patientName': function () {
        var tmpCollection = Patients.find() // `enter code here`
        tmpCollection.forEach(function (myDoc) {
            var a = Patients.find({"UserID": myDoc.UserID}).fetch().concat(user.find({"UserID": myDoc.UserID}).fetch())
            return a;
            console.log(a);
        });
    }
})
```

and at template side I am showing the data like this

```
{{#each patientName}}
    <tr>
        <td>
            {{FirstName}}
        </td>
        <td class="f20">
            {{LastName}}
        </td>

        <td>{{Gender}}</td>
        <td>{{age}}</td>
        <td>{{Email}}</td>
        <td>{{HomePhone}}</td>
        <td>{{CellPhone}}</td>
        <td>{{Fax}}</td>
        <td>{{AddressLine1}}</td>
        <td>{{AddressLine2}}</td>
        <td>{{City}}</td>
        <td>{{State}}</td>
        <td>{{Zip}}</td>
        <td>{{IPAddressCreatedFrom}}</td>
        <td>{{MaritalStatus}}</td>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the collection's **[`map()`](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/map)** method to iterate over the cursor, access the patient documents and use the **[underscore](https://atmospherejs.com/meteor/underscore)** method **[`_.extend()`](http://underscorejs.org/#extend)** to generate a merged list of the patients and users joined on the `UserID` field. The following demonstrates this:

```
Template.showpatient.helpers({
    'patientName': function () {
        var merged = Patients.find().map(function(patient){  
            var user = User.findOne({"UserID": patient.UserID}) // get the 
            return _.extend(patient, user); 
        });
        console.log(merged);
        return merged;
    }
})
```